# Guessing the word from context

Tags: machine-learning

Can I train a system to decide, which one of suggested words is more likely to appear in the sentence being analyzed? For example, if I have sentence "I was playing with my ______ when I heard the bell ring" and list of words "dog", "lock", "smoke", "coke", can I train the system to arrange these words in the order of likelihood? What machine learning algorithms should I consider?

Answer (score 1):

This is standard imputation in Natural Language Processing (see for instance http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~mcollins/courses/nlp2011/notes/pcfgs.pdf). Though, I don't think you should expect to get what you expect every time. What you expect will depend on what you train the system with. I am sure you are aware that the order of likelihood is highly subject to the training data you use